# Replacing initial probability in $G(n,\frac{1}{2})$ with $G(n,\frac{1}{3})$ for not appearance edges

Tags: probability-theory, random-graphs

I have a question; maybe so simple but practical:

In Erdos-Renyi binomial random graph $G(n,p)$; set $p=\frac{1}{2}$. So with probability $1/2$ some edges will appear and some not.

Now the question is what kind of graph will we obtain if we replace $p=\frac{1}{2}$ with $p'=\frac{1}{3}$ for not appearance edges; in other words, if in $G(n, \frac{1}{2})$ for $v_i \nsim v_j$ we draw the edge $v_i v_j $ in $G(n, \frac{1}{3})$; then by considering the union of all the edges in the mentioned graphs and assuming that these two graphs are independent; then what will be the gained graph in our initial model?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking: are you saying that there are two distinct colors of edge in your graph?  Or are you 'supplementing' your graph with the additional edges?  If the latter, then trivially you get $G(n, \frac23)$...

Comment: @Steven Stadnicki , Yes yes, the second one; we 'supplementing' the graph with the additional edges? How you are saying trivially? Can you please give me more details or put it as an answer? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Still unclear: are you considering the union of all the edges in $G(n,\frac12)$ and in $G(n,\frac13)$, assuming these two graphs are independent?

Comment: @Did , Yes, I am considering the union of the edges as "D Poole" has explained in his answer. I will accept his answer. Is very clever and also beautiful answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the graph is distributed as $G(n, p')$ for some $p'$. Why? Clearly the appearance of an edge in the final graph is independent of the choices for the other edges. Fix an edge $e$ and so $p' = P(e \text{ appears in final graph})$. Now, note that 
$$
\{e \text{ appears in final graph}\} = \{e \in \text{intermediate graph}\} \cup \{e \notin \text{intermediate graph}, e \in \text{final graph}\},
$$
This is a disjoint union and these probabilities should be straightforward to calculate.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I like your answer.